# Why do parsing HTML with regex questions come up so often?

Tags: discussion

I mean is it really such a common desire/requirement? Or is someone out there trolling SO on a huge scale?

Comment: [Related](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @badp The NPR login page? Does SO automatically rewrite SE beta links if you don't have access to them?

Comment: @Michael - yes (my fault for copy pasting the rewritten link).

Comment: @badp now that's just cruel to those of us who weren't invited!

Comment: @Josh, I didn't [commit to the (public) proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related) either :)

Comment: There must be some kind of conspiracy going on...

Comment: @Josh: http://stackmobile.com/site.php?site=programmers.stackexchange

Comment: `Or is someone out there trolling SO on a huge scale?` Is ***this*** a trolling question?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Wanting to parse HTML is common.  People think it should be easy.  And they know a little bit about RegEx.  And it just seems like the perfect fit because they've used it for smaller input.  Regular languages isn't in their vocabulary.  They don't understand what that means.  They just know that HTML is a language, so clearly it should work!

Comment: This doesn't explain why they pop up so damn often. I mean every single one of these people has failed to Google [parse html regex](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=parse+html+regex&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and read the first result...

Comment: You're incorrectly assuming people try to solve their own problems before asking someone else.  They pop up so often because parsing HTML is common.  It's that simple.  There are a ton of questions across the wide spectrum of SE sites that could *just* be answered by searching.

Answer (score 10):

Because when a developer first starts to figure out the power of Regular Expressions, they can get a little over excited. I certainly went through a phase where I wanted to write my own parsers for everything.

But I think "why do they come up so often" isn't as important as "what should we do about them."

A comment made by [@bgould](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365690/bgould) on the question [Big Regular expression help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612633/big-regular-expression-help) struck a chord with me:

> He's not asking for a diatribe on why he shouldn't.

A lot of these questions are directed to the ever-popular [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454) but that question-answer isn't useful to an OP because it's more of a cultural phenomenon than an answer. I'm not saying there isn't useful information there; I'm saying that most OPs directed that way - who are new enough to not know that they shouldn't parse (X)HTML with RegEx - won't see the answer through the fun and the horror. Then they don't get the answer they *should* get and that affects SO's *raison d'être*.

Additionally, those users who find that question while checking if their question would be a duplicate may just ask again if they don't understand it, or it doesn't offer as concise an answer as they need.

So I think we need to answer these questions or find a better answer to direct them to, which focuses on communicating the point as opposed to the use of poetry and Unicode.

Comment: Great answer.  The only thing more tiresome than the question coming up repeatedly are the knee-jerk "don't ever try to do that" answers that get posted as a result.  There are plenty of simple things you can parse out of HTML with regular expressions, and that's often all anyone is trying to do.  Automatically linking to @bobince's answer just shows that people either aren't reading the question, or they don't really understand the issue to begin with.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard - Well, I still agree that one shouldn't ever try to do that, but it merits better justification than is provided by most users.

Comment: Mental note: start a band and call it "Poetry and Unicode"

Comment: The worst thing about that question is that there is no useful information for the user, at least not without digging through it.  All the poor user sees is a wall of text that makes no sense whatsoever.  That answer is only funny to those of us who understand why HTML parsing with regexes is hard.

Comment: @BilltheLizard There seems to be no way to get people to stop linking to bobince’s amusing but hopelessly unhelpful answer, since locking doesn't block that. And we'd need dev help to even delete it, since it has all those dupes now. Part of why people uses regexes for HTML snippets is because they use regexes in their text editors for both simple searches and for search-and-replace operations, but this is very rarely pointed out.

Answer (score 9):

Because processing HTML is a common need, and normally people parse strings using regular expressions, so they naturally try to do the same with HTML. Then they run into problems, for obvious reasons

Answer (score 5):

Is someone trolling out there on a huge scale? No

However, the most viewed question on stackoverflow is on this topic - with 1.1 million views (8-1-14):

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Why is this the most viewed question? Well for different reasons.

Wanting to parse HTML is common because if you know a little bit about both, it seems like a good match at first.

That doesn't justify the amount of traffic generated in relation to this topic - I believe the real reason is because of the embellished accepted answer on the top viewed question.
It - like many things on the internet - has taken on a life of its own.

It's become a joke... an internet fad.

I asked my co worker a few weeks ago if I could parse HTML with regex. At first he couldn't tell that I was trolling him - he became very animated and laughed at me - and then continued to tell me how bad of an idea it was.

Has he ever even needed to parse HTML? No - he works primary with python and R.

The point is that people LOVE showing that they know something that others don't - and people also love a spectacle. For some reason this internet fad has an element of both.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to rant on stackoverflow, but being the better man I chose meta stackoverflow.

> > Why do parsing HTML with regex questions come up so often?

The answer is because the FUD of being unable to parse html with regex is circulated around by `computer science experts/programming noobs` all over the internet which leads to such monumental confusion as to causing people to go on stackoverflow and ask for random internet n00b opinions on the subject of the matter even if they know better.

Now I get what they are saying, at least what the computer science experts are saying, in that regular expressions are *not* a good match for parsing hierarchically structured languages, but when extracting data, most of the time you *aren't* parsing hierarchical structures, you are indeed matching a repeating pattern in a piece of text with parts that contain your target data.

CSS/Xpath parsing does have its advantages in that it can sometimes be even *simpler* than regex parsing. I even wrote a [sample C++11 web crawler](https://github.com/nurettin/pwned/blob/master/curl/formicator.hpp) that uses curl to crawl pages while storing sessions and utilizes the [beautiful hcxselect](https://github.com/jgehring/hcxselect) library to parse the html pages visited using css.

The whole point of regex is being able to validate a subcategory of domain specific language texts or extract useful information from said texts using subgroups of repetitive patterns. The latter being ubiquitous in data science and API building. [citation not needed for anyone with enough parsing experience]

Seriously, I have no idea why computer scientists are being such nerds and programming noobs are being such bitches on this subject. The longer and more specific your regular expression is, the lower the chance of mis-extracting useful information from hierarchic data, which shows up in your goddamn tests anyway. It's not like you're gonna go "duuh I'm not getting some of the data with regex, it's too complicated for me, uh well, it compiles so ship it".

And don't even get me started on the amount of bugs you can accrue with xpath and css parsing, not to mention what an API change (ie. when a pointy haired boss gets tired of how the company website looks) will do to your neatly hierarchical code which could have been *Flat* and *Maintainable*.

And what time have you lost trying to parse your data with regex? Just the time to write those regexes and test them, which, frankly is not that long if you are good at them, are using good test data representative of the real task and are using the correct tools that highlight your matches and show matched regex groups anyway.

So yeah, for many cases you don't need "the html noob pack" or the "nokogiri xpath css matcher" which will give you an exact match for your groups and subgroups of data, you can simply extract it from flat expressions.

So if possible, use a clever regex and match subgroups to extract your goddamn data. And yes, the turkish guy with bajillion-times-upvoted stackoverflow answer is hilarious, but apparently in that post he doesn't appreciate fine vocabulary or thoughtfulness more than creating internet memes.

Comment: Filtering out the rant, there's actually a simple message here and it's "you _can_ parse simple/known-structure/with-limitations html with a regex". It's a message that is chastised because, if handed out indiscriminately, it does not help the OP in the long term when they try to scale up their "extract all .foo links from a page" regex to something a bit less trivial. That said the canonical question doesn't help much either because the top-voted answer surely reads like a mis-formatted "I wonder why I was linked here" mess to novice programmers.

Comment: "the turkish guy with bajillion-times-upvoted stackoverflow answer is hilarious, but apparently in that post he doesn't appreciate fine vocabulary or thoughtfulness more than creating internet memes"

Jelly?

Answer (score -4):

My honest opinion is that people take what they know about coding (string searching functions, RegEx, etc.) and try to find a way to parse HTML.

It definitely is not recommended, time consuming and HTML is never guaranteed to be valid (tag wise). I would recommend using the [HTML agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)